# find kth non-repeating element among characters and integers (large size)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is a question i found over internet , asked in an interview .

> Given a very large array of character and integers we had to find the K th non repeating element.
>   For eg: if the array is  { 1,2,a,s,2,s,b,v }
>   and if K=3
>   then the answer should be 'b' .

required constraints : `O(N)` time and `O(1)` space .

**What have i done ?**

The best solution i can come up with is make array of size `256` and hash the elements as they come .
I think this to be a valid solution because size of array `256` is independent of input array size .

I also tried to use `Kth-order statistics` approach , but could not form an algorithm , because many numbers can be repeated before and after the kth required element , so it's not possible to determine it's location .

**What do i  require ?**

> Please share your views and how would you approach it.
>   I don't want any code .

Comment: what is wrong with your solution? I like it, it uses O(1) memory and works in O(n) time

Comment: i want to know how to apply Kth-order statistics approach

Comment: if you know, that array contains only English letters and digits, you can decrease array size to 28 + 10 items... or even can go further and keep  only 38 bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach will work only if you consider the alphabet as a constant size, and will fail miserably for [unicode32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), for example.

Note however that since this is a variation of the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) - I believe this problem cannot be solved otherwise within the time and space constraints.

**Proof:**

Assume you had such an algorithm that uses "real" `O(1)` space, and `O(n)` time. Let this algorithm be `A`.

Given an instance of element distinctness problem, `arr` - use `A(arr,n)`. The algorithm should return `arr[n]` (1 based), if and only if every element in the array is unique. Since `A` is `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space - we solved element distinctness problem in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.